# textview value does not save to model using rxswift behaviorrelay

Tags: swift, textview, rx-swift

I have this vc
https://github.com/vlainvaldez/kwizapp/blob/master/kwizapp/Quiz/QuizCreator/QuizCreatorVC.swift

that generates a cells same cells for each horizontal scroll
https://github.com/vlainvaldez/kwizapp/blob/master/kwizapp/Quiz/QuizCreator/QuizCreatorCell.swift

Im passing a model for each cell called Quiz

```
cell.configure(with: self.quizes[indexPath.row])
```

https://github.com/vlainvaldez/kwizapp/blob/master/kwizapp/Models/Quiz.swift

inside the Quiz model ihave

```
public let questionBehavior: BehaviorRelay<String> = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
public let answerBehavior: BehaviorRelay<String> = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")
```

which are about to have an input upon text change in the cell: QuizCreatorCell.swift

but then when I try to scroll next then go back the Im setting the textviews to

```
self.questionTextView.text = quiz.questionBehavior.value
self.answerTextView.text = quiz.answerBehavior.value
```

Im expecting the values will still be there but it is not even I used a class which a reference type

Comment: The links are all broken.

Comment: @DanielT. oh sorry I made it private, but the solution was to make the disposeBag inside the cell 

`private var disposeBag: DisposeBag! `

and make it:

`public override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.model = nil
        self.disposeBag = nil
        self.questionTextView.text = ""
        self.answerTextView.text = ""
    }`

Comment: Okay. Don't make your disposeBag an implicitly unwrapped optional though. That's bad form.